# Linear Regression error - InvalidArgumentError: assertion failed: [Labels must be <= n_classes - 1] [Condition x <= y did not hold element-wise:]

Tags: tensorflow, linear-regression

I am doing a linear regression model in TensorFlow. I have applied the code I saw on a course with my own dataset but I am getting an error I don't understand:

[image]

This is a link to the Google Colaboratory where the code is written:
[Colaboratory](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1DQGF3zUsq3PQm9FtL7lY5M8aiNJsG4-A?usp=sharing)

The problem must be on my dataset because with the dataset from the course it works, but I can't figure out what the problem is exactly.

Comment: Looking at the error message it seems you are using the same number of labels as you have classes, whereas the number of labels has to be less than or equal to the number of classes minus 1.

Comment: I see the error message, but I don't understand what are the labels or the classes it is talking about.